# The [downloadfile] has been destroyed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The tag [downloadfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile) (508 questions, no tag wiki) does not indicate the contents of the questions, and in most cases the [download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/download) tag should suffice.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? Is it unambiguous?**

No, it is used either as a substitute for [download] or for one of several different tools or libraries known as "DownloadFile".

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

No, file downloading is not inherently on-topic.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not really, nearly all of them could work well with [download] plus a tag for the language or API being used.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, it seems to mean several different things:

- A synonym for the [download] tag.
- The DownloadFile Drupal module.
- The DownloadFile API method in .NET.

Let's get rid of this tag. Most of the questions should be retagged [download] if they do not have it already, and have applicable language or API tags added as appropriate.

Comment: [tag:file-download] already is a synonym for [tag:download]. And there's a bunch of questions tagged with both [tag:file]+[tag:download].

Comment: @Bergi and all of them useless.

Comment: It looks *really strange* seeing a box at the top of the question reading "The tag under discussion here is being considered for *immediate* removal" (emphasis mine) when the post is *almost two years old*. Surely that isn't the normal speed around here?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The burnination process only started two days ago. It's not automatically added to the post, it was manually added two days ago, and getting them started and done both take time

Comment: Yup, 2 years is not normal speed, some of them like [like] took 7 years.

Answer (score 12):

[downloadfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- .NET questions about the webclient DownloadFile-function can be retagged to [webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webclient).
- Spring Boot questions about the Spring webclient can be retagged to [spring-webclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-webclient)
- Replacing the tag with an appropriate language and/or library tag (if applicable) should suffice for most other questions

## Progress:

The [downloadfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=downloadfile),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdownloadfile%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdownloadfile%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdownloadfile%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdownloadfile%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242034/burnination-of-the-downloadfile-tag)
- [Track progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=396092)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [downloadfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [downloadfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [downloadfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloadfile) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.